# Can I add text.toLowerCase(); to an already functioning script?

Tags: javascript, string, lowercase

I'm using this script:

```
    function validateform() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('textareabox');
  var word = '<?php echo $answerbutton_of_this_page ?>';

  var textValue = textarea.value;
  if (textValue.indexOf(word) != -1) {
    document.getElementById("correcto").innerHTML = '<?php echo $outputvali_of_this_page; ?>';
    return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("incorrecto").innerHTML = 'Incorrect!';
  }
}
```

I'd like to add:

```
document.getElementById("textareabox").value = text.toLowerCase();
```

But I cannot get it to work. Where or how should I add this? 
I want the script to first lowercase the input and then see if the user has the correct / incorrect answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change:

```
var textValue = textarea.value;
```

To:

```
var textValue = textarea.value.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Indeed! thank you so much. Could you explain in short why there?

Comment: That is where you declared the textvalue variable by taking the value from the textbox. So - just implement the toLowerCase function on the value. A vote up and marking the question as solved will be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you please click the "V" button under the rating so this answer will be set as correct ?

Comment: No problem. Happy coding :)